# Laravel: Send emails only if the email is not on bounce list

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, amazon-ses

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and the SES driver in order to send my emails.
I've set up my database and routes so that, whenever I send an email that returns as a bounce, I get a notification and add this email to a table of "invalid emails".

Now I need to setup my app so it only sends an email if the email is NOT in this bounce table. It's a check that will be made for every single email sent by this app, with no exceptions.

Is there an easy way to make this check on the email driver, or do I need to change all calls to the Mail facade and check this before sending the email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest creating your own `Mailable` class which inherits from `\Illuminate\Mail\Mailable`.

There is a method there called `buildRecipients()` which looks like this:

```
/**
 * Add all of the recipients to the message.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Mail\Message  $message
 * @return $this
 */
protected function buildRecipients($message)
{
    foreach (['to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'replyTo'] as $type) {
        foreach ($this->{$type} as $recipient) {
            $message->{$type}($recipient['address'], $recipient['name']);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

You could hook in to (override) this and add some logic to only add the recipient if he is not on the "blocked" list.